# phonegap android app for google map geolocatin issue

Tags: android, cordova, dictionary

I am making phonegap android application for geolocation. But it doesn't show google map.My code is as follow. I installed geolocation plugin for cordova. And it run proper upto alert of geocode in below code. I am testing with android mobile.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Properties Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
}
function onSuccess(position) {
alert("success");
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
            'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
             var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
             var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
             ReverseGeocode(latitude,longitude);  
}

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
function ReverseGeocode(latitude, longitude){
alert("geocode");
var reverseGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
alert("location");
var currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
alert("position");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: First on location services from your mobile setting OR Follow this link without plugin Map: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037702/how-do-you-display-map-google-on-a-phonegap-android-application/26038477#26038477

Answer (score 1):

**How to show a Google map in your Phonegap app using Google Map api V3?**

1. Start by adding a reference to Google maps api in index.html:

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then add a div that will contain the map. Choose an id like “map_canvas”. That id will be used to add our map from our javascript later on.

```
<div id="map_canvas">
</div>
```

**2. Create a new javascript file called googlemap.js in the www folder and add the following content:**

```js
function GoogleMap(){
     
    this.initialize = function(){
    var map = showMap();
    }
     
     var showMap = function(){
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
     
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
     
    return map;
    }
    }
```

and add a reference to it in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="googlemap.js"></script>
```

the mapOptions variable contains information about zoomlevel, where the center of the map is and what kind of map we want to show.
And the line containing the map variable uses getElementById to get our map_canvas and adding the map.

**3. Showing the map**
To show the map we must run the initialize function in googlemap.js. Since we are using the example index.html from phonegap we add these lines to the onDeviceReady function in index.html

```
function onDeviceReady(){
var map = new GoogleMap();
map.initialize();
}
```

Now run the app and you should se a map over Australia.
**4. Adding markers**

To add markers to our map we use the LatLng and Marker object from Google API.
Edit the initialize function in googlemap.js to look like this:

```js
function GoogleMap(){
 
this.initialize = function(){
var map = showMap();
addMarkersToMap(map);
 }
```

and add the following function, called addMarkersToMap:

```js
var addMarkersToMap = function(map){
var latitudeAndLongitudeOne = new google.maps.LatLng('-33.890542','151.274856');
 
var markerOne = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latitudeAndLongitudeOne,
map: map
});
 
var latitudeAndLongitudeTwo = new google.maps.LatLng('57.77828', '14.17200');
 
var markerOne = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latitudeAndLongitudeTwo,
map: map
});
 }
}
```

**5. Zooming out the map to show all markers**
To zoom out the map without knowing which zoomlevel to use we are going to use the LatLngBounds object from the Google Map API.

Start off by adding the following line first in the addMarkersToMap function:

```
var mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

and before the closing tag of the function add these lines:

```
mapBounds.extend(latitudeAndLongitudeOne);
mapBounds.extend(latitudeAndLongitudeTwo);



map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
```

The addMarkersToMap function now looks like this:

```js
var addMarkersToMap = function(map){
var mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 
var latitudeAndLongitudeOne = new google.maps.LatLng('-33.890542','151.274856');
 
var markerOne = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latitudeAndLongitudeOne,
map: map
});
 
var latitudeAndLongitudeTwo = new google.maps.LatLng('57.77828', '14.17200');
 
var markerOne = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latitudeAndLongitudeTwo,
map: map
});
 
mapBounds.extend(latitudeAndLongitudeOne);
mapBounds.extend(latitudeAndLongitudeTwo);
 
map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
 }
```

Now we’re done, run the app and the map now zooms out so you can see the marker which we added in Sweden.

Comment: It gives warning like "URL blocked by whitelist: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false". My phonegap version is : 3.5.0-0.21.17

Comment: plz refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423558/phonegap-google-maps-api-v3-not-displaying-at-all-on-android

Comment: let  me know your result? I am wait for your response

Comment: you will also refer this. i think it is a more helpful for you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146231/google-map-wont-show-in-phonegap-ios-app

Comment: I got blank white page nothing more. And getting error as i told above.

Comment: If you don't mine show me your updated code and what you trying? cfprabhu@yahoo.com