# phonegap GeoLocation values for location to know

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

my program is working properly which is giving the correct lattitude and longitude values.

But the problem is how do i use to show the customer that he is from this LOCATION.

I read the phonegap GeoLocation [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition) i didn't find any solution. they are having diocumentation for how to take values from there API `GeoLocation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this script

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And try to use this,

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

lat = position.coords.latitude;
lng = position.coords.longitude;
var geocoder;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
    },
    function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var add = results[0].formatted_address;
                var value = add.split(",");

                count = value.length;
                country = value[count - 1];
                state = value[count - 2];
                city = value[count - 3];
                alert("city name is: " + city);
            } else {
                alert("address not found");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    }
);
```

});

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined                             onSuccess @ dashboardPageCtrl.js:33

Comment: since i'm using phoegap i have not added any API which relates google maps

Comment: Have you added above mentioned script tag before dashboardPageCtrl.js?

Comment: no the phonegap actually gets me the results of lattitude and longitude by the object position. which is inside dashboardpagectrl and i have a function for success of finding lat and lag there i have added your script.

Comment: What I mean to say is try to add <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script> before you include your dashboardPageCtrl.js in html page.

Comment: Is your phone connected with internet as that script is going to download online js? And kindly paste your full error.

Comment: yeah it is connected to internet the error i was getting is.....     Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: I have updated my code. Please check the code from starting and let me know.

Comment: This code is working properly for me. Try to check from starting.

Comment: do i need my location to initialize http://www.phonegapspain.com/topic/problema-geolocalizacion-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined/

Comment: I have simply used above mentioned code and added below mentioned permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: there is some problem with Phonegap API geolocation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423558/phonegap-google-maps-api-v3-not-displaying-at-all-on-android   thankyou

Answer (score 0):

For phonegap Geolocation API please `whitelist` the `google api` whisch is at `access` in `config.xml` and `android.manifest.xml` also look into this [solution at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423558/phonegap-google-maps-api-v3-not-displaying-at-all-on-android) for phonegap Maps and also follow the answer of dhruv.