# google maps is not show in cordova android, but show in browser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps

hello i am new in cordova and google maps, i have build simple google map in my cordova project. my code is working properly in browser, but when i have built into apk and install in device, google maps is not show.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data gap  https://*.google.com  https://*.googleapis.com  https://*.gstatic.com  https://*.googleusercontent.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map">Maps</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script> 
</body>
```

index.js

```
 var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Are you also using [PhoneGap plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html)?
If yes, please try the suggested solutions on this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423558/phonegap-google-maps-api-v3-not-displaying-at-all-on-android) and please also check this [GitHub post](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it like this. Test seTimeout, maybe you don't need this..
I hope this will help you.

```
function loadScript() {
              var script = document.createElement("script");
              script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap";
              document.body.appendChild(script);
            }
            setTimeout(function(){ loadScript() }, 1000);
```